# Programatically fill TFS New Bug workitem from VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am wondering if it is possible to have VBA (Access) open a TFS Bug report webpage and fill in the description ?

While I am able to open the page I have not yet found a way to populate the description and potently other fields.

Perhaps one of the experts knows?

Comment: What are your requirements? Where is the bug data coming from that you can even automate the population of the bug?

Comment: My hope is to have my access database code fill in as much of the TFS page as possible when an error is captured.  So the data is coming from my access code (VBA)

Comment: Why are you tracking the bugs in access instead of TFS?

Comment: I am not tracking the bugs in access; access is producing the bugs.

Comment: What do you mean producing the bugs?

Comment: Are you testing a VBA / Access application and want to log information from the current page into TFS?

Comment: Just that....  Something has gone wrong in the access application and it throws an error.  This gets reported into TFS currently by the user copying and pasting the error message and filling in the required fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I finally did it is to use a dll to interface between access and tfs...
For anyone trying to do the same here is the code...

```
Imports Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
Imports Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client
Imports Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<ComClass(TFSInterOp.ClassId, TFSInterOp.InterfaceId, TFSInterOp.EventsId)> Public Class TFSInterOp
Public Const ClassId As String = "14306fc5-1492-42d6-a032-bc4348508dd3"
Public Const InterfaceId As String = "288339cb-0c2e-45fd-8005-e5fed401f0cc"
Public Const EventsId As String = "723327dc-7777-44e4-b291-9299027665eb"

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public Function InsertBugWorkItem(Title As String, Desc As String) As String

    Dim tfsServer As String = My.Settings("TfsFullPath").ToString ' {YOUR TFS SERVER PATH}
    Dim strAssUser As String = My.Settings("AssignTo").ToString
    Dim teamFoundationServer1 As Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(New Uri(tfsServer))

    Dim workItemStore1 As New WorkItemStore(teamFoundationServer1)
    teamFoundationServer1.Authenticate()
    Dim WorkItemStore As WorkItemStore = New WorkItemStore(tfsServer)
    Dim tfsProject As Project = WorkItemStore.Projects(0)
    Dim wIType As WorkItemType = tfsProject.WorkItemTypes("Bug")
    Dim workItem As WorkItem = New WorkItem(wIType)
    Dim wiStore = teamFoundationServer1.GetService(Of WorkItemStore)()
    Dim Project = wiStore.Projects
    Dim Area = Project.Item(0).AreaRootNodes("BITS").Id ' The project to add the work item to

    ' Prefill items
    workItem.Title = Title
    workItem.Description = Desc
    workItem.AreaId = Project.Item(0).AreaRootNodes("BITS").Id
    workItem.Fields("Assigned To").Value = strAssUser
    workItem.Fields("System Info").Value = "Access V 1.1.25"
    workItem.Fields("Repro Steps").Value = Desc

    Dim result As ArrayList = workItem.Validate()

    If result.Count > 0 Then
        Return (result(0).ToString + "There was an error adding this work item to the work item repository")
    Else
        workItem.Save()
    End If

    ' Open the new item in explorer
    Dim myService = teamFoundationServer1.GetService(Of TswaClientHyperlinkService)()
    Dim myUrl = myService.GetWorkItemEditorUrl(workItem.Id)
    Dim oProcess As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    oProcess.StartInfo.FileName = myUrl.ToString
    oProcess.Start()
    Return "OK"
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to do what you are working on.

One, trusting a buggy application to correctly report its own bugs isn't a great idea. But beyond that you will be trying to attach Access to TFS.

That being said you *can* do this entirely automated. Put in some error trapping and then what you are looking to do is how to call TFS APIs. But you may or may not have to install some third part tools etc.

[Starting point](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2007/07/30/team-system-web-access-power-tool-available.aspx) [TFS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130307%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)